# Accessing a property in python from outside of a method

Tags: python

Lets say I have the following code:

```
class MyClass(obj):
    @property
    def product(self):
        return self._product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._product = kwargs.pop('product')
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    field = self._product.name
```

So as you can see, I am trying to set the variable field using the property _product, but obviously, I get the error that `self is not defined.`, but what can I do to actually access the property from a local variable within the class?

Comment: Outside of the method, the instance doesn't yet exist (neither does the class, for that matter). So what does `self` refer to? If you want `field` to expose the product's name directly, *make it another `@property`*.

Comment: Let's say that doing this were possible. Suppose you eventually create two MyClass instances that each have a product, named "Widget" and "Sprocket" respectively. What value would `MyClass.field` have? The answer can't be "either Widget or Sprocket, depending on which instance you use to access it" because class attributes are shared. If you want an attribute that isn't shared, you can use instance attributes, which are conventionally created inside the `__init__`. And conveniently you won't get `self is not defined` if you try to refer to self there.

Comment: What is your goal? You are trying to solve a problem but obviously this approach doesn't work. So what is the problem to be solved?